# Parallax Scrolling CSS

Tags: css, parallax

Well, this is my first question here!

1. I've been having a problem in making `background-attachment: fixed;` happen    on a `<div>` which is also assigned this property :- `transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);`. Actually on the first slide, the background image is rendering correctly, but on the rest slides, the image is not visible.
2. Also, the scroll bar is not working when I click or drag it.

I've tried a lot of times on google and it's been two days. At last I tried Stackoverflow, 'cause I was not able to get the specific answer which I wanted.

If I missed some link then please do help and pardon me.

Here's the page which I'm making - http://mynk-9.github.io/test/

**[edit]** Now, I've also added the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Parallax Scrolling Effect</title>
  <style>
   body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   }
   div.parallax-page {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 1px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 50%;
    perspective-origin-x: 50%;
   }
   div.parallax-page > div.group {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
   }
   div.parallax-page > div.group {
    margin-bottom: calc(100vh);
   }
   div.parallax-page > div.group:last-child {
    margin-bottom: -25vh;
   }
   div.parallax-page > div.group > div.background {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
   }
   div.parallax-page > div.group > div.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   }
   
   div.parallax-page::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /*display: none;*/
   }
   /* using formula -> scale =  1 + (translateZ * -1) / perspective */
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>  
  <div class="parallax-page">
   <div class="group">
    <div class="background" style="background-image: url('sample-wallpaper.svg');"></div>
    <div class="slide">
     <h1 style="text-align: center;">A magical scroll!!</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="group">
    <div class="background" style="background-image: url('sample-wallpaper-2.svg');"></div>
    <div class="slide">
     <h1 style="text-align: center;">A magical scroll!!</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="group">
    <div class="background" style="background-image: url('sample-wallpaper-3.svg');"></div>
    <div class="slide">
     <h1 style="text-align: center;">A magical scroll!!</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="group">
    <div class="background" style="background-image: url('sample-wallpaper-5.svg');"></div>
    <div class="slide">
     <h1 style="text-align: center;">A magical scroll!!</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On `div.parallax-page > div.group > div.background` you have `width:100vw` which overlaps onto the scroll bar thus *hiding* it from the mouse. If you change that to `100%` the scroll bar will work. Otherwise, the backgrounds show up great for me in Chrome.

Comment: Hey Mayank, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add your code directly to the question, please? Or at least, an "MCVE" of the code? Questions asking for help with code that has some kind of problem in it" need to include that in order to get better quality answers.

Comment: @Octopus I did what you said, I made it 100% instead of 100vw, but now, a small gap has emerged up on the left. How to tackle this? I also tried giving `div.parallax-page > div.group > div.background` a property of `left: -1%` and the gap disappeared, but now the gap is on left.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-red.css">

<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

/* Create a Parallax Effect */
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

/* First image  */
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/19/17/16/rainbow-background-1149610_960_720.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Second image  */
.bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4AA4qYGunr4/maxresdefault.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
}


/* Adjust the position of the parallax image text */
.w3-display-middle {bottom: 45%;}

.w3-wide {letter-spacing: 10px;}

.w3-hover-opacity {cursor: pointer;}


</style>
<body>

<!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <ul class="w3-navbar" id="myNavbar">
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-padding-large">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="w3-hide-small w3-right">
      <a href="#" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-red"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- First Parallax Image with Text -->
<div class="bgimg-1 w3-opacity w3-display-container">
  <div class="w3-display-middle">
    <span class="w3-center w3-padding-xlarge w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide w3-animate-opacity">MY <span class="w3-hide-small">WEBSITE</span> LOGO</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (About Section) -->
<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="about">
  <h3 class="w3-center">ABOUT ME</h3>
  <p class="w3-center"><em>I love photography</em></p>
  <p>We have created a fictional "personal" website/blog, and our fictional character is a hobby photographer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
    qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    </div>



<!-- Second Parallax Image with Portfolio Text -->
<div class="bgimg-2 w3-display-container">
  <div class="w3-display-middle">
    <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">PORTFOLIO</span>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="w3-container w3-theme-dark w3-padding-16">

  <p>Powered by <a href="#" target="_blank">csandreas1</a></p>
 
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I know that, what you've done is just fixed background-attachment to the view-port, I know how to do that, but **what I really needed was also the movement of the background image**, but relatively slower than the normal scroll speed. And, yes, I could have done it with JS, but doing so compromises with performance, old devices may not handle it. That thing which you've done, I've already accomplished -- [My Web Framework(like bootstrap)](http://mynk-9.github.io/MSD-Web-Framework)